# How to Exclude folder from compile in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I have imported mvn project but not able to run and compile any files

i have dir structure like project name/src/com/test/java

but my all classes have package name "com.test" but residing on path "/src/com/test/java"

so my question is how to exclude last folder, here is "java" in my project.

Comment: Can you share the package declaration of one of your classess?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to move some directories.

Maven project structure sais you have directory

```
src/main/java/   for application files and
src/test/java/   for test cases.
```

And your packages within that.

So you'll need yoir classes in

```
src/main/java/com/test/   or
src/main/java/com/test/
```

In project properties you can then set source dirs to src/main/java (remove src first if you still have that)

Check your eclipse Path settings:

[image: Eclipse Path settings]

Be sure to include the root-folders to your packages. So if your packages are com/test you'll want src/main/java/ as root folder.

If unclear, please share how your project is configured.

Comment: my actual files resides inside path " /src/com/test/java" , but eclipse take source folder is "src" but in eclipse how can i compile or what setting need to my file can compile excluding "java" dir ,                                                                 ,i am able to compile and run using mvn but not through eclipse